# Getting the wrong output in array

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have been trying to get the correct outcome from an array. I have tried everything I can think of.  I am new to VB.Net and programming.

I have a file on usb that I am getting an array from. the txtfile is set up to give me the years and the number associated with that year.
for example.
year 21
1
year 19
6
year 18
18
year 17
12
and so on.

I am trying to find the year with the greatest number and display it in a label.

I am getting the year 21 because it is the highest, but I actually need the year with the highest associated number in this case it would be year 16 with 27 as the associated number.

here are the parts of the code that I believe are assoiciated with it. I have written to find it but I am getting the first year only which is actually year 21.

the first line or years is `_strYears(_intSizeOfArray) as string`

the second line or number assoiciated with the years is `_strNumberOfHurricanes(_intSizeOfArray as integer`

option strict must be on for the assignment

```
    Dim intAverage As Double
    Dim intYear As Integer
    Dim intMostYears As Integer = 0


    '   Calculate the Statistics and display the results
    For intIndex As Integer = 0 To _intSizeOfArray
        If intYear < _intNumberOfHurricans(intIndex) Then
            intYear = _intNumberOfHurricans(intIndex)
        End If
        intAverage = intAverage + _intNumberOfHurricans(intIndex)
    Next

    intAverage = intAverage / _intNumberOfHurricans.Length
    For intLoopCounter = 0 To _intSizeOfArray
        If _strYears(intMostYears) < _strYears(intLoopCounter) Then
            intMostYears = intLoopCounter
        End If
    Next



    '   Display the statistics for the Storm Average in the selected Year
    '   and the most active year within the range of year.
    lblNumberOfHurricanes.Text = "The Number of Hurricanes in the  " &
        _strYears(intChoiceSelected) & " is " & _intNumberOfHurricans(intChoiceSelected).ToString() & "."
    lblAvergeNumberHurricanes.Text = "The Average Number of Storms was " & FormatNumber(intAverage, 1) & " Hurricanes."
    lblMostStorms.Text = "The" & _strYears(intMostYears) & " with " & intYear & " Had The Most Storms Between " &
        (_strYears(20) & " And " & (_strYears(0)))
```

The results I am getting are the first two labels are correct and the last label is displaying year 21 which should 16, and 27 which is correct, and year 21 and year 1 which is correct.

please this assignment is due in 1 and 1/2 hours,  i have been trying to get this all day.  if anyone can give me an idea of where this is wrong. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you use exact name of the labels, exact outcome you expect and the outcome you are getting? Currently it is getting a bit confusing to follow "first label, last label" thing.

Comment: I am sorry for being confusing.   I need to find the year with the most storms in it. so the answer I am looking for is "Year 2005" because it had 27 storms in that year. what I am getting is "Year 2010" because it is the biggest year but only has 12 storms.    sorry about that

Comment: Does the year 2010 has lowest number of storms? It seems you are trying to get the least no. of storms in the first loop, and not the most.

Comment: Hi,  I just looked at the txt.file.  no 2009 has the least amount of years.

Comment: Wait, this line of code.`If intYear < _intNumberOfHurricans(intIndex) Then intYear = _intNumberOfHurricans(intIndex) End If`

What is this supposed to do? Currently it is comparing the actual year, to get the biggest year which is 2010 in your case.

Comment: That first loop is getting the results of a combo box selection from 1990 to 2010.  it is displaying the number of storms in the year selected.  the loop also finds the average of storms and displays that.   it also is providing the highest number of storms. the 2nd loop should find the year with the most storms and display the year.

Comment: Well, it doesn't actually. Your first loop will always return 2010. Because you are comparing the year, not the count of storms in that year. Am I safe to assume that `_intNumberOfHurricans` will have the count of hurricanes per year? And the actual year no might be stored in `_strYears` where `strYears(0)` will say Year 2005, and `_intNumberOfHurricans(0)` will say 27 (the actual count for year 2005). Is that a safe assumption?

BTW, you should set intYear to a value by default. Considering your loop tests for the value before it get set, that might cause problem later.

Comment: I did not look at that because I am getting the right numbers for my text labels.  but now that you say that. I might have my labels written to get the right results.  if that is the case do I need the second loop? may I ask you how would I get the "Year 2005"?

Comment: The "Year 2005" is supposed to be in the _strYears array though.

Comment: If the index order is same, why not save the index in a variable. Like after the line `intYear = _intNumberOfHurricans(intIndex)`, you do `maxIndex = intIndex`. So, when the loop ends, you know what is the index.

Then you can directly go `"The" & _strYears(maxIndex) & " with " & intYear &`. So, no more second loop.

P.S. change the name from intYear to intHurricaneCount or something like that. Currently it sounds like '2005' will be typical value in intYear which is the actual year, and not the count of storms in the year.

Answer (score 1):

These 3 lines will do most of what you're trying above. Since this is an assignment, I'm not sure if your teacher would allow you to use Linq, but since you haven't specified anything like that, this should give you some light for the future if nothing else:

```
Imports System.Linq

Dim intAverage As Double = _intNumberOfHurricans.Average()
Dim intMostYears As Integer = _intNumberOfHurricans.IndexOf( _intNumberOfHurricans.Max())
```

Now you can display this info in your labels just like you're doing.

Comment: HI.  Thank you so very much.  I tried to enter the imports System.linq and it will not let me.  probably because I have to have option strict on.      so I added the other two lines and I am getting a "index of error".     This has to be something I am missing.  There has to be a way to look at the file. and get the year with the highest number.          Again  thank you for letting me try that.   I do appreciate it.

Comment: @RonEHillsJr.: I can't think of a good reason for the errors you're describing. `System.Linq` reference is generally available out-of-the-box in new VB.NET projects, so `Imports` should work. Note that `Imports` should be the first line of your code (top of the file). The other two lines should replace the code that you have shown above (except the label update line), nothing else.